# Default argparse argument value is not set when a custom namespace is object

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-3.6

I have noticed that the default argument value is not set when the custom namespace object is used:

```
import argparse

class CliArgs(object):
    foo: str = 'not touched'


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', default='bar')

args = CliArgs()
parser.parse_args(namespace=args)
print(args.foo) # 'not touched'

print(parser.parse_args()) # 'bar'
```

ideone: https://ideone.com/7P7VxI

I expected `bar` to be set in both cases.

Is it expected? I cannot see it in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#default) though.

And if it's expected, is there then really no way to implement that other than using some *custom* action?

UPD: I reported it as a documentation bug https://bugs.python.org/issue38843

Comment: Hmm, it looks to have been that way since forever:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/argparse.py#L1793-L1796   Seems buggy to me.

Comment: Hum... I cannot find a common way in the source code. The attributes in the namespace object are treated as the default already, so the default from `add_argument` won't be processed at all.

Comment: @wim it's just so that it was easier to distinguish between "the value was not set" and "it was set to an empty string". `not touched` there is purely for that reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's expected. *EDIT: But only for argparse developers.*

See `argparse.py`

```py
def parse_known_args(...):
    # add any action defaults that aren't present
    for action in self._actions:
        if action.dest is not SUPPRESS:
            if not hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
                if action.default is not SUPPRESS:
                    setattr(namespace, action.dest, action.default)
        # add any parser defaults that aren't present
        for dest in self._defaults:
            if not hasattr(namespace, dest):
                setattr(namespace, dest, self._defaults[dest])
```

> add any action defaults that **aren't present**

In your example if you set attribute in default object, effect will be the same:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', default='bar')

args = argparse.Namespace()
args.foo = 'not touched'
parser.parse_args(namespace=args)
print(args.foo) # 'not touched'
```

Comment: So it's undocumented?

Comment: It seems so. I've just finished reading documentation and I can't find any description. But it is no surprised for developers how you see the code. I'm very surprised. It could be side effect.

Comment: I have reported a documentation bug https://bugs.python.org/issue38843